# Issue with REGEX in javascript

Tags: regex

I get an issue using REGEX, it is probably about my REGEX but I need some helps.

I need to match all string containing "D"...

```
Test string 1 : D
Test string 2 : aaaaaaDqqqqq
Test string 3 : Dssssssss
Test string 4 : D4564646
Test string 5 : 1321313D2312
Test string 6 : ppppprrrrrr
```

My regex :

```
/^.+D.+|(:?^|\s)D$/gi
```

It works only for 1 and 2 and it should works for 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.

Comment: Maybe [`^.*D.*$`](https://regex101.com/r/L63Meu/1)? Or `[^D]*D[\s\S]*`.

Comment: Thank you it works with `.*`.

Comment: However, it seems you may just use `indexOf` or `includes`, which is a more natural way to check if a char exists in an input string in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

In your case problem is with `+` operator which is literally `Matches between one and unlimited times` so it wont work if letter "D" will be in the beggining or the end of string. Try this regex: `^.*D.*$` with asterix, as it is defined as `Matches between zero and unlimited times`

[See example](https://regex101.com/r/S6OPDG/1)

Comment: `^.*D.*$` is inefficient and will choke on multiline input. Do not use it.

Answer (score 0):

Following regex should work for you

```
.*D.*
```

Comment: `.*D.*` is inefficient and will choke on multiline input. Do not use it.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is test for whether or not a string contains a `D` character, it's just `/D/`

```js
var tests = [
"D",
"aaaaaaDqqqqq",
"Dssssssss",
"D4564646",
"1321313D2312",
"ppppprrrrrr"
]

tests.forEach(str => console.log(/D/.test(str)))
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using a regex simply use the `includes` function

```js
var string = "aaaaaaDqqqqq",
substring = "D";
if(string.includes(substring)){
    console.log("contain")
}else{
    console.log("don't contain")
}
```